# USB Huawei LTE modem - after restart USB isn't connecting

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, usb-modem, modem

the thing I'm trying to do is to restart LTE modem:

```
Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
```

which I do with simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "0000:00:1a.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/unbind
echo -n "0000:00:1d.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/unbind
echo -n "0000:00:1a.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/bind
echo -n "0000:00:1d.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/bind
```

That works (I guess), because it cause that I'm disconnected from LTE, and modem is still present in lsusb. However I can't reconnect to the LTE network (is available but after few seconds of trying it shows the message, that I'm disconnected).

In that case only plug out and plug in modem manually helps.

My main goal is to renew my IP address each x minutes without my participation. So it should be done from command line (crontab) or bash script (which will also runs as cron). Is it possible?